# how to remove really the nvidia driver from debian 10

Tags: debian, package-management, drivers, nvidia

I'm trying to remove the nvidia driver from my system (running with debian 10). I tried several methods,but unsuccesfully. Something like these :

1. apt remove nvidia-driver
2. apt-get purge nvidia-driver

after that,when I reboot the PC,debian 10 restarts and I see this :

> mario@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/home/mariozio# lspci -nnk -d 10de
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU102
>   [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti] [10de:1e04] (rev a1)
>         Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti] [19da:2503]
>         Kernel driver in use: nvidia
>         Kernel modules: nvidia

what to do ?

Comment: Suggest you [edit] your question and include the output generated when you input the two commands.  The driver probably isn't named `nvidia-driver`.

Comment: Also, how exactly did you install it?

Answer (score 7):

Answer from debian wiki applied when something went wrong with nvidia driver:

> hit Ctrl+alt+F2
>
> login as root

```
apt-get purge nvidia.
```

> (**don't forget the "." dot**) It erases every package with "nvidia" on its name

```
/etc/init.d/gdm3 stop # (gdm3 for gnome 3)
apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg
apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
killall Xorg
reboot
```

> Xorg should reconfigure itself, **if not** run a terminal and pass

```
X -configure
```

debian wiki: [Backing out in case of failure](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Backing_out_in_case_of_failure)

Answer (score 1):

The kernel modules of the `nvidia` driver may still be present in your initramfs. Use `update-initramfs -u` to rebuild your initramfs file without the `nvidia` driver modules.